# Cycle2 remove cycle-sentinel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my try:

Initialization:

```
function carouselInit(path, var1){
    $(path).cycle({
       fx: 'carousel',
       slides: '> box',
       timeout: 0,
       prev: '#prev-'+var1,
       next: '#next-'+var1,
       visibleSlides: 4
    });
}
```

Destroy:

```
function carouselDestroy(path){
    $(path).cycle('destroy');
    $(path).find('.cycle-sentinel').remove();
    $(path).find('.ctrl').hide();
}
```

**The problem** : my destroy function doesn't remove the cycle-sentinel div.

If I try to remove it with css (`.path .cycle-sentinel { display: none !important; }` ) it gives me an error:

> c error undefined on line 6;

Comment: The `destroy` function should remove the sentinel slide for you, you just need to call `$(path).cycle('destroy');` and that's it. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hxafyct/) for an example. If you inspect the slider you will see the sentinel slide then click the destroy button and you'll see it disappear.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was that cycle sentinel and I finally managed to remove it with: `autoHeight: false` .